# Extracting a stored procedure COUNT result from the DataSet in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, dataset, ado.net

I am running a stored procedure returning the result of a `COUNT` on a huge `SELECT`.

I find myself having a DataSet as a result in my C# code but after numerous tries I fail to extract the result of the `COUNT`.

Here's my code, you can ignore the long Stored procedure It's just a `COUNT (*)` in the end, but it's there in case.

---

C# Code:

```
internal int ObtenirCount(string ProcedureName, IConnexionBD _ConnexionBD, params SqlParameter[] parametres)
{
    int count = 0;
    IConnexionBD _ConnBd = _ConnexionBD ?? new ConnexionBD(ObtenirChaineDeConnexion());

    DataSet ds = _ConnBd.ExecuteDataSet(string.Format(ProcedureName, NomTable), parametres);

    if (ds != null && ds.Tables.Count > 0 && ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        count = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; // Doesn't work
    }
    return count;
}
```

---

Stored Procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[PSS_us_net_010]
@PageSize int,
@PageNumber int,
@filtreType varchar,
@filtrePrincipal varchar,
@filtreNumUtilisateur varchar,
@filtreNom varchar,
@filtreCourriel varchar, 
@filtreCompteCentral varchar,
@sortColumnUser varchar

AS

DECLARE @Sort char(35)
DECLARE @StartRow int
DECLARE @strFiltreType varchar(100) = ''
DECLARE @strFiltrePrincipal varchar(100) = ''
DECLARE @strFiltreNumUtilisateur varchar(100) = ''
DECLARE @strFiltreNom varchar(100) = ''
DECLARE @strFiltreCourriel varchar(100) = ''
DECLARE @strFiltreCompteCentral varchar(100) = ''
DECLARE @strSortColUser varchar(100) = ''

SET @StartRow = CAST(((@PageNumber - 1)*@PageSize + 1) AS varchar(50))
IF @filtreType != ''
    BEGIN
        SET @strFiltreType = @filtreType
    END
IF @filtrePrincipal != ''
    BEGIN
    IF @filtrePrincipal = 'o' OR  @filtrePrincipal = 'u' OR @filtrePrincipal = 'i' OR @filtrePrincipal = 'ou' OR @filtrePrincipal= 'oui' OR @filtrePrincipal = 'ui'
        SET @strFiltrePrincipal = 00
    ELSE 
        SET @filtrePrincipal = NULL
    END
IF @filtreNumUtilisateur != ''
    BEGIN
        SET @strFiltreNumUtilisateur = @filtreNumUtilisateur
    END
IF @filtreNom != ''
    BEGIN
        SET @strFiltreNom = @filtreNom
    END
IF @filtreCourriel != ''
    BEGIN
        SET @strFiltreCourriel = @filtreCourriel
    END
IF @filtreCompteCentral != ''
    BEGIN
        SET @strFiltreCompteCentral = @filtreCompteCentral
    END
IF @sortColumnUser != ''
    BEGIN
        SET @strSortColUser = @sortColumnUser
    END

BEGIN

    SELECT COUNT(*)FROM
    (
   SELECT
     ty_util_net,
     ident_util_net,
     no_usager_net,
     nip,
     nip_temporaire,
     adr_courriel,
     dte_creer,
     dte_modif,
     dte_dern_utilisation,
     hre_dern_utilisation,
     nb_visites,
     nom_prenom,
     dte_avant_dern_util,
     hre_avant_dern_util,
     adr_courriel_erronee,
     phrase_mot_passe,
     nom_navigateur,
     version_navigateur,
     date_env_courriel,
     ChoixAucunePhrase,
     EnvoiCourriel,
     DetCCReg,
     IndAffPhrase
   FROM us_net
    WHERE nom_prenom >= @Sort 
    AND(@filtreType IS NULL OR ty_util_net LIKE '%' + @strFiltreType + '%')
    AND(@filtrePrincipal IS NULL OR no_usager_net LIKE '%' + @strFiltrePrincipal + '%')
    AND(@filtreNumUtilisateur IS NULL OR ident_util_net LIKE '%' + @strFiltreNumUtilisateur + '%')
    AND(@filtreNom IS NULL OR nom_prenom LIKE '%' + @strFiltreNom + '%')
    AND(@filtreCourriel IS NULL OR adr_courriel LIKE '%' + @strFiltreCourriel + '%')
) AS countResult 
END
```

Comment: Your stored procedure returns a count? And you access Rows.Count? This will only count the number of rows in your DataTable. Access the value of it don't count the rows.

Comment: isn't this what ExecuteScaler is for?

Comment: @Sebi Yeah that's a beginner's mistake I guess hehe.

Comment: @DartFeld shit happens ;)

Comment: Your procedure has some serious issues. None of your varchar parameters have a scale defined. This means they use the default size. Do you know the default size of a parameter? It is either 30 or 1, it changes based on context and I can never remember which one is which. And why the subquery? You don't need to select all the columns just to get a count. Just select count(*) from us_net....

Comment: @SeanLange I fixed the subquery by deleting the SELECT and all the columns. I will go learn what parameter scales are. Thanks a lot for looking into that, it helps a ton.

Comment: The scale is "how many". For a varchar(100) the scale is 100. Like you have in your local variables. But your inbound parameters do not have a scale defined. Don't waste your time determining what the defaults are, define the size (or scale) of you varchars every single time.

Comment: And not trying to bust your chops or anything but you have several things in here that are just kind of odd. You pass in PageSize and PageNumber, then you do some math on them....and then they never get touched again. You also have a Sort variable but it never gets set to anything so the value is null. This means you query will never return any rows. Either this query is just an example for posting with a lot of stuff removed or it is serious need of an overhaul.

Comment: @sean lange Indeed it is a fast stripped down version of my stored proc since it was so long and i just wanted to show the count select mostly :) thanks a lot for the scale info, learning a lot today thanks to the generous people here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of that stored procedure is in the first row, **first column**.
The property Rows.Count return always 1 in this context because its purpose is to count the number of rows present in the DataTable

So your code should be simply

```
count = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0]);
```

As noted in comments, when you need just a single scalar value like the ones returned by COUNT, SUM or any single row/single column query, you should think to use ExecuteScalar. It is a lot more efficient because it doesn't need to build DataSets, DataTables and all the infrastructure required to support these objects.

Comment: you missing the Column access :p .Rows[0][0]

Comment: I had tried count = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0] and couldn't find a .column after. Didn't think it was a 2D array .. Well that explains it all ! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to use your existing implementation, Why use `ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count`?

Just stop at `ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0]` this will give you the item in the row directly. Make sure you convert/cast. Since the stored procedure is already giving the count.

Answer (score 1):

```
count = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0]);
```

You should try this. because it will be first first  table first row and first column.

I would suggest better to use [ExecuteScalar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx) or [DatabaseExecuteScalar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.enterpriselibrary.data.database.executescalar.aspx), if you want to retrive only single value. DataSet is heavy. DataSet is to be used where We have to get data in table form and We need to read/write the DataSet.

Comment: I didn't know the existence of ExecuteScalar, I'm kind of new to SQL. I'll look into it thanks !